# New and old CoreData model

Tags: ios, core-data, submission

I want to create new version of an app (created by others) using a new CoraData model. 
My doubt is: The core data model is permanent through updates. I want to be sure that the previous CoreData model doesn't create problem with the new version of the App.

Have I to follow some Best practices?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want to keep old app data and do a migration or not.

If not then on publishing a new model, when core data will see that the model is different from old one, you can erase the store with the following method :
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];

Then recreate your store :

```
[__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];
```

You'll be notified that the store doesn't match in the

```
/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
```

method, you'll find it typically in your appDelegate.

basically you have two options : create a new store according to your new model (old data will vanish) or migrate your old model to new one (is it possible according to what you're gonna do?)

If the app is fundamentally different, you could consider publishing a "new app" not a new version. You need then to redirect users to new app like with a message in old app. Basically it is the case when you want old users keep their app "as is" because it is conforming to old iOS version and publish a brand new app using brand new iOS features, standards, user interface.

Comment: Pushing a new app is not a solution, I'll lose all the app users, Am I wrong ? 

When you say "when core data will see that the model is different from old one, you can erase the store..." How I'll be warned  about the fact that the App find a different model?